# How I could use pivot table Pandas as with group-bye

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, accounting

I'm strugling to solve one issue with a dataframe that I have.

| ID | date | x1 | x2 | x3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 | 25 | 50 | 56 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | 2 | 9 | 17 |

I have to transform my dataframe above for this model below:

| ID | date | description | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 | x1 | 25 |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 | x2 | 50 |
| 1 | 2023-09-01 | x3 | 56 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | x1 | 2 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | x2 | 9 |
| 1 | 2023-08-01 | x3 | 17 |

Is it possible?

Imagine that we are working on a balance sheet (financial statements).......

Tks a lot

Comment: Try: `df.melt(id_vars=['ID','date']).sort_values('date', ascending=False)`